# Creating and comparing dates from current week to a cell.innertext string value

Tags: c#, string, date, compare

I need to compare a cell's value to dates in the scope of the current week.

I need to see if a date from a cell can be matched to any date in the current week. If so, success Match should be incremented.

I was thinking about putting dates in an array or dictionary and then compare it to a cell value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime cellValue = DateTime.Now;
var beginweek = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays( (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek *-1);

var endweek = beginweek.AddDays(6);

if (cellValue.Date >= beginweek.Date && cellValue.Date <= endweek.Date)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Nice one, but cellValue is a string = "12/29/2011 1:33:11 AM" and now there is a problem converting it to DateTime to be able to validate dates...

Comment: DateTime.Parse(); converts a string to datetime

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, this also works:

DateTime cellDateValue = Convert.ToDateTime(((HtmlCell)cell).InnerText);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Week** class of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public bool IsInCurrentWeek( DateTime test )
{
  return new Week().HasInside( test );
} // IsInCurrentWeek
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with a solution based on Jeremy's answer. The difference is that I used

```
DateTime cellDateValue = Convert.ToDateTime(((HtmlCell)cell).InnerText);
```

instead of

```
DateTime cellValue = DateTime.Now;
```